# Is it possible to custom SharePoint list multiple rows edit form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

Is it possible to custom SharePoint list multiple rows edit form?

I am trying to use PowerApps Form to customize SharePoint list form?

For creating a new row or modifying existing row, the power apps form show correctly.

But, If I select more than 1 rows, and then click edit, my custom form will not show, something like below:

The Forms seems to be SharePoint default multiple rows edit screen.

Is it possible to custom this form?

[image: Meekou_0-1675321502424.png]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to customize the "Bulk Edit properties" form of SharePoint online lists using Power Apps.

You can only customize the new/display/edit forms for individual (single selection) list items in SharePoint online list.

When you try to edit properties for multiple list items using "Bulk Edit properties" option, it will open SharePoint default forms only.

Comment: Is there any way custom `Bulk Edit properties` form without PowerApps?

Comment: I don't think so. Check if it is possible using SPFx form customizer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer

Comment: I create a starter project by following the link. It seems SPFX only support `Create`, `Edit` and `View`

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought!